# Apache protect and Rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, authentication

I have a url `www.mywebsite.com/admin` and I want to password protect it using this

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Files"
# (Following line optional)
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile /usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords
Require user SomeUsername
```

However, the site is using a custom framework so `/admin` gets passed through `index.php`, so there isn't actually an `admin` folder so I can't put it in a .htaccess file in it. How can I protect that url using the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `mod_setenvif` with `mod_auth` like this:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI /admin SECURED

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Files"
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile /usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords
Require user SomeUsername
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=SECURED
Satisfy any
```

Comment: Would that just go in the .htaccess file in my root directory?

Comment: Just put it there now, works like a charm, thank you :)